# RVM gradient of likelihood

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, likelihood, derivative, gradient

Can somebody tell me how Tipping (2001) in his [classical paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume1/tipping01a/tipping01a.pdf) about the Relevance Vector Machine arrives at the following expressions
\begin{align}
\mathbf{D} &= (\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{t}\mathbf{t}^{T}\mathbf{C}^{-1}-\mathbf{C}^{-1}) \mathbf{\Phi} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \\
&= \beta[(\mathbf{t}-\mathbf{y})\boldsymbol{\mu}^{T} - \mathbf{\Phi}\Sigma]
\end{align}

where
\begin{equation} 
\mathbf{C} = \beta^{-1}\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{\Phi} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^{T}, \\
\boldsymbol{\mu} = \beta^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{\Phi}^{T}\mathbf{t}, \\
\boldsymbol{\Sigma} = \left( \mathbf{A} + \beta \mathbf{\Phi}^{T} \mathbf{\Phi} \right)^{-1}
\end{equation}

which contain the derivatives of likelihood
\begin{equation} 
\mathcal{L} =  -\frac{1}{2}\big[N\log 2\pi + \log\left|\mathbf{C}\right| + \mathbf{t}^{T}\mathbf{C}^{-1}\mathbf{t} \big]
\end{equation}

with respect to the elements $\phi_{mn}$ of the design matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$ (i.e. $\mathbf{D}_{mn} = \partial \mathcal{L} / \partial \phi_{mn}$)?

Note that bold small letters e.g $\mathbf{t}$ denote $N\times 1$ vectors, bold capital letters $N\times N$ matrices, and $\mathbf{A}$ is diagonal. Also, the author makes frequent use of the following identity (by the Woodbury inversion lemma) which might be helpful:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{C}^{-1} = (\beta^{-1}\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{\Phi} \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^{T} )^{-1} = \beta \mathbf{I} - \beta \mathbf{\Phi}\left( \mathbf{A} + \beta \mathbf{\Phi}^{T} \mathbf{\Phi} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^{T} \beta = \beta \mathbf{I} - \beta \mathbf{\Phi} \mathbf{\Sigma} \mathbf{\Phi}^{T} \beta
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

I also asked on math.stackexchange and got an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422933/steps-in-derivative-of-matrix-expression) to the above question.

Comment: Why the downvote? Or to frame it differently, what else could I have done to lead people from this post to the answer?